# How can i split those lists in on list using for loops in single line?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I want to make list flatten([[list1], [list2], [list3] ....]) from pandas

Can someone tell me how to make 'for loop' in single line? Thanks
(Is there any other way to solve this?)

```
words = []
for sent in train['tokenize']:
    words += sent
```

The result i want is [[list1], [list2], [list3]] >> [list1, list2, list3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list comprehension`:

```
words = [a for sub in train['tokenize'] for a in sub]
```

Or [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from  itertools import chain
words = list(chain.from_iterable(train['tokenize']))
```

**Sample**:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'tokenize':[['a','s','d'],['ss','dd'],['aa','ss','dd']]})
print (train)
       tokenize
0     [a, s, d]
1      [ss, dd]
2  [aa, ss, dd]

words = [a for sub in train['tokenize'] for a in sub]
print (words)
['a', 's', 'd', 'ss', 'dd', 'aa', 'ss', 'dd']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `functools` & `operator`, use `[[1,2,3], [4,6], [7,8,9,8]]` as an example, it pick every sublist from the nested list, and add them together to form a one-dimensional list.

```
import operator  
from functools import reduce  
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 6], [7, 8, 9, 8]]  
print(reduce(operator.add, a))
```

Output:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add all lists to on

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 6], [7, 8, 9, 8]]  
sum(a,[])
```

Out:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8]

​
```